# How to pass parameter while navigating to previous screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I am navigating from screen A to screen B.. And then navigation back to screen A using

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```

I want to know how can we pass parameter while doing this?

here is my code

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { View, Text, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
 import Card from './Card';
 import CardSection from './CardSection';
 import MyButton from './MyButton';


 class Settings extends Component{
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   ip:'',
   port:''
 };
}

onSaveClick() {
 console.log('Button clicked');
 this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
render(){
const { input, container } = styles;
return(
  <View style = {container}>
  <Card>
  <CardSection>
    <TextInput 
      style = {input}
      onChangeText = {(ip) => this.setState({ip})}
      placeholder = "IP Address"
      autoCapitalize = "none"
      autoCorrect = {false}
      keyboardType = "numeric"
    />
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection>
      <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      onChangeText={(port) => this.setState({port})}
      placeholder="Port Number"
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      keyboardType = "numeric"
    />
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection>
      <MyButton onPress ={this.onSaveClick.bind(this)}>
        Save
      </MyButton>
    </CardSection>
    <View>
    </View>
   </Card> 
  </View>
);
}
}
```

So how can I manage to access state of this component in the previous component. Can we pass state as a parameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You should follow the Redux methodology

Because passing state / information back from child component to parent component (second screen to first screen) is a bad design pattern as this creates multiple paths of data flow in application which makes it hard to Debug .

## How **redux** helps is

1. When click of submit you push the data onto a global store .(Basically dispatch an action and use reducer to update global redux store)
2. Navigate back to the previous screen .
3. List to these changes in previous page via connect( from react -redux package) and reflect the changes .

You can use the node package react-redux .

And follow up the example from here -> http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html

More helpful examples [here](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/react-redux-tutorial-d1f6c6652759) .

Comment: Thank you. For the detailed Explanation. I will certainly look forward to follow this design pattern.

Comment: But as for now, my app has only two screens. So i've figured out a way without Redux. I am passing a callback to update state as navigation params to second screen. And through it am updating the previous component's state. As my app has only two screens , I think this is okay.

Comment: It could be very well argued that a pattern where you open a screen and it passes data back to the previous screen isn't a bad design pattern for many cases, especially if you're comparing it to using some global data storage to pass the state back(and for that there's a million ways to do that).

I would very much like to see a way to navigate for result.

Anyhow, this answer seems just like a plug/advert for redux instead of providing a direct answer besides the "use some global storage hack", which itself is kind of obvious answer to a problem like this.

Comment: easier to use context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html and why not using AsyncStorage for a small issue like this? I believe you start using Redux after a deep understanding of the advantages and not just because you want to persist some information between screens. For example I would start using Redux if I need a global store for state, not just because I want to use the same state between 2 different screens.